# Python selenium function return True If image exists in page

Tags: python, selenium, stream

I'm trying to do something with live streams on social media and when someone send a gift to streamer I want to know what gift is that so I need a function which is returns True when the selected gift .png exists in page.

That code part which is I select as a solution work perfectly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

def checkString(yourstring):
    if yourstring in driver.page_source:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(checkString('googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

def checkString(yourstring):
    if yourstring in driver.page_source:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(checkString('googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'))
```

Comment: Can i search my string in just a spesific <div>  </div> ?

Comment: You can use re.findall(r'<div>(.+)<\/div>')

Comment: i try to do it but cannot see the .png files in the files like they are not here

Comment: algorithm just pass them, is it happening maybe links are in the <img src= > format ?

Comment: With regex findall you can find any string. Read the python regex documents

Comment: like there is a tons of .png in page like that, so i need to find if this photo contains special element which i found it by using find_elements and for loop together. in so many span classes, they have a pictures and i need to know if that pictures equals to mine

Answer (score 0):

How about Beautifulsoup?

```
parser = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

and then call find_all, if you have an example I can be more specific :)

Comment: im trying to get <img src="link.png"> , and its in span element. let me show u with photo : https://i.imgur.com/04dzHsb.png i can't get it

Comment: like i wanna get the upper span u know, and when this text founded in the span it returns x, but there is so many element like that. And i need to use find.elements method to find them, but i cant get that img

Answer (score 0):

How about this xpath?

```
'//img[contains(@src, ".png")]'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'src'

Comment: i must to use find_elements and its not working with that

Comment: Please show the code of what you tried to do